# How to find the points in which a given curve intersects itself?

Tags: calculus, parametric

Apologies in advance for my lack of knowledge with *tex.

Hi everyone and thanks for any sort of help!

I am given the following parametric curve:

$(t^2\cos t, t^2\sin t,t^2), \text{where} -2\pi \le t \le 2\pi $

There's one known intersection of the curve with itself at $(4\pi^2,0,4\pi^2)$ and I know that there is at least one other intersection within the given domain, but I have no idea how to find it.

I've gone ahead and graphed the curve on desmos:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pTbE.png)

I searched the internet for a bit and found other examples, but they involve simple linear equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $t$ and $s$ are two times when the curve is at the same point, then $t^2 = s^2$. So $t = \pm s$. The first case is silly. In the second case $\sin t = \sin s = \sin(-t) $, which implies...

Comment: Thanks for the response! What do you mean by "if s and t are two times..."?

Comment: $\gamma(s) = \gamma(t)$, if $\gamma$ is the curve.

Answer (score 0):

The Hint of AreaMan is perfect for the solution (+1). I suggest a visual interpretation that can help.

Your graph is the projection of the curve in the $(x,y)$ plane, so self intersection of the curve are also self intersections in this projection. The projection of  the point $(4\pi^2,0,4\pi^2)$ is the point near $x=40$ in the graph, that is reached when $t=2\pi$ and when $t=-2\pi$ ( note that the coordinate $z$ is the same for opposite values of $t$).

The other point where the curve self intersect is projected at the point near $x=-10$, that is reached whan $t=\pm \pi$ and has coordinates $(-\pi^2,0,\pi^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for chipping in. My problem is that I didn't really understand how we ended up with $t^2=s^2$. I figured that we need to use t and s in the equations, solve them like:

$t^2cos(t)=s^2cos(s)$, $t^2sin(t)=s^2sin(s)$

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The curve self intersects if we have two values $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that: $(t_1^2\cos t_1, t_1^2\sin t_1,t_1^2)=(t_2^2\cos t_2, t_2^2\sin t_2,t_2^2)$.  Let $t_1=t$ and $t_2=s$, we have $t^2=s^2$ from the coordinate $z$ and from the other coordinates we have $\cos t=\cos s$ and $\sin t=\sin s$.